# xml response with unescape characters in jmeter 3.1

Tags: jmeter

I am bit new to Jmeter (3.1) but i have a big task to complete with it.

I have configured jmeter to hit 1 million http requests and everything is fine

the xml response what i get into the log file is with escape characters but what i want the log file need to be saved with unescape characters,

```
<httpSample ng="41" na="41">   <responseData class="java.lang.String">&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;methodResponse&gt;&lt;params&gt;&lt;param&gt;&lt;value&gt;&lt;struct&gt;&lt;member&gt;&lt;name&gt;avail ableServerCapabilities&lt;/name&gt;&lt;value&gt;&lt;array&gt;&lt;data&gt;&lt;value&gt;&lt;i4&gt;536871488&lt;/i4&gt;&lt;/value&gt;&lt;value&gt;&lt;i4&gt;8&lt;/i4&gt;&lt;/value&gt;&lt;/data&gt;&lt;/array&gt;&lt;/v alue&gt;&lt;/member&gt;&lt;member&gt;&lt;name&gt;negotiatedCapabilities&lt;/name&gt;&lt;value&gt;&lt;array&gt;&lt;data&gt;&lt;value&gt;&lt;i4&gt;0&lt;/i4&gt;&lt;/value&gt;&lt;/data&gt;&lt;/array&gt;&lt;/value&gt; &lt;/member&gt;&lt;member&gt;&lt;name&gt;originTransactionID&lt;/name&gt;&lt;value&gt;&lt;string&gt;1606456&lt;/string&gt;&lt;/value&gt;&lt;/member&gt;&lt;member&gt;&lt;name&gt;responseCode&lt;/name&gt;&lt;value& gt;&lt;i4&gt;139&lt;/i4&gt;&lt;/value&gt;&lt;/member&gt;&lt;/struct&gt;&lt;/value&gt;&lt;/param&gt;&lt;/params&gt;&lt;/methodResponse&gt;</responseData> </httpSample>
```

what i want is

```
<methodResponse><params><param><value><struct><member><name>availableServerCapabilities</name><value><array><data><value><i4>536871488</i4></value><value><i4>8</i4></value></data></array></value></member><member><name>currency1</name><value><string>TZS</string></value></member><member><name>dedicatedAccountDeleteInformation</name><value><array><data><value><struct><member><name>dedicatedAccountID</name><value><i4>1402</i4></value></member><member><name>dedicatedAccountUnitType</name><value><i4>6</i4></value></member><member><name>dedicatedAccountValue1</name><value><string>5368535040</string></value></member><member><name>expiryDate</name><value><dateTime.iso8601>99991231T12:00:00+0000</dateTime.iso8601></value></member><member><name>startDate</name><value><dateTime.iso8601>00000101T12:00:00+0000</dateTime.iso8601></value></member></struct></value></data></array></value></member><member><name>negotiatedCapabilities</name><value><array><data><value><i4>0</i4></value></data></array></value></member><member><name>originTransactionID</name><value><string>1606684</string></value></member><member><name>responseCode</name><value><i4>0</i4></value></member></struct></value></param></params></methodResponse>
```

Please help !

by the way, how can i save originTransactionID and responseCode into csv file.

Please throw some light on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save XML response "as is" as the following 5 characters needs to be escaped in XML files:

1. `"`
2. `'`
3. `<`
4. `>`
5. `&`

So if you need only `originTransactionID` and `responseCode` to be saved you can take the next steps:

1. Add [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above XML
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Reference name: `originTransactionID`
   - XPath Query: `//member/name[text()='originTransactionID']/../value/string/text()`
3. Add another XPath Extractor and configure it like:

   - Reference Name: `responseCode`
   - XPath Query: `//member/name[text()='responseCode']/../value/i4/text()`
4. Add the next lines to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
   sample_variables=originTransactionID,responseCode
   ```
5. When you run your test next time you will see 2 extra columns in .jtl results file, they will hold `originTransactionID` and `responseCode` values for each of the requests

References:

- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)

Comment: When you say those 5 characters need to be escaped, does it mean that i need to write another script to convert those unescaped to escaped ? After doing some google search, most of them recommend a script in python or perl. By the way many thanks for your suggestion regarding xpath extractor